# Web service authentication with multiple authentication types

Tags: forms-authentication, web-services, authentication

I am trying to pull data from the list.asmx web service from a console application.  I am using clams based authentication, and whenever only integrated Windows Authentiation is checked everything works fine.  Whenever I also check Enable Forms Based Authentication I start getting an Acccess is denied error when I try to connect to the service.  I can login successfully using FBA so I don't think the problem is caused by the FBA configuration.  Does anyone have any ideas to what might be causing this?

Comment: Could be to do with the the selection page you get for mixed mode authentication web-apps.  If SP doesn't know which method to use I guess you would get an access denied, not sure though (hence comment not answer)

Comment: I thought about that, but I'm not sure how you can tell it which one to use.

Answer (score 3):

Your client (the program consuming the service) needs to pass a NetworkCredential object. With integrated auth, this just happens. For FBA, you need to create a new object and put in the credentials. For claims auth, you need to leverage the Identity Framework.

Comment: Sounds pretty logical to me +1

Comment: Does anyone have an example of using the Identity Framwework to authenticate to the SharePoint services?